# Simple loop with good performance in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, performance, pointers, haskell, time-complexity

I am starting in Haskell and am interested in how to get matching performance for simple code I would normally write in C or Python.  Consider the following problem.

You are given a long string of 1s and 0s of length `n`.   We want to output, for each substring of length `m`, the number of 1s in that window. That is the output has `n-m+1` different possible values between `0` and `m` inclusive.

In C this is very simple to do in time proportional to `n` and using extra space (on top of the space needed to store the input) proportional to `m` bits.  You just count the number of 1s in the first window of length `m` and then maintain two pointers, one to the start of the window and one to the end and increment or decrement depending of whether one points to a 1 and the other points to a 0 or the opposite occurs.

Is it possible to get the same theoretical performance in a purely functional way in Haskell?

Some terrible code:

```
chunkBits m = helper
  where helper [] = []
        helper xs = sum (take m xs) : helper (drop m xs)

main = print $ chunkBits 5 [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Mind that Haskell uses lazy programming. In some circumstances, for instance if you turn out to be interested in only the five first numbers, the time complexity can be O(1).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You will need to read in m+4 bits in that case don't you?

Comment: @eleanora: given your window looks to the future, yes. If it would look to the past, it requires only the first 4 (or m, if m is less).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is correct, since m is not dependent on the length of the bit string, and is therefore considered a constant in O() notation.  Have you timed any tests to find out whether Haskell can compete?  I expect Haskell to beat Python, but lose by a small margin to C, assuming equal quality code for each, and the numbers would be a nice resource to post.

Comment: @MattJordan I was assuming that m grows as well as n but it's not an important detail.  My interest is not so much in practical speed but rather in just how to actually write the code in a purely functional style so that it at least has the same theoretical performance (up to constant factors).

Comment: Well, that's not a bad thing to ask, but you should start out with some implementations of your own and a demonstration of how they do _not_ give the desired performance.

Comment: @MattJordan `m` may not depend on the length of the int string, but it *is* part of the input size (contributing O(lg m) bits) if the algorithm does not include a fixed `m` as part of its definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C Code

Here is the C code you've described:

```
int sliding_window(const char * const str, const int n, const int m, int * result){
  const char * back  = str;
  const char * front = str + m;
  int sum = 0;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < m; ++i){
     sum += str[i] == '1';
  }

  *result++ = sum;

  for(; i < n; ++i){
    sum += *front++ == '1';
    sum -= *back++  == '1';
    *result++ = sum;
  }
  return n - m + 1;
}
```

### Algorithm

The code above is apparently *O(n)*, since we have `n` iterations. But lets go a step back and have a look at the underlying algorithm:

1. Sum the first `m` elements. Keep this as `sum`. *O(m)*
2. Our first window has `sum` 1s. *O(1)*
3. Until we've exhausted our original string: *O(n)*

   1. "Slide" the window. *O(1)*

      - add 1 to `sum` if we gain a `'1'` by sliding *O(1)*
      - subtract 1 from `sum` if we lose a `'1'` by sliding *O(1)*
   2. Push `sum` onto the results. *O(1)*

Since `n > m` (otherwise there is no window), *O(n)* holds.

### Moulding a Haskell variant

That's basically a left scan (`scanl`) with a way to get a list of those differences in (2.1.). So all we need is a way to somehow slide:

```
slide :: Int -> [Char] -> [Int]
slide m xs = zipWith f xs (drop m xs)
  where
    f '1' '0' = -1  -- we lose a one
    f '0' '1' =  1  -- we gain a one
    f  _   _  =  0  -- nothing :/
```

That's *O(n)*, where *n* is the length of our list.

```
slidingWindow :: Int -> [Char] -> [Int]
slidingWindow m xs = scanl (+) start (slide m xs)
 where
   start = length (filter (== '1') (take m xs))
```

That's *O(n)*, same as in C, since both use the same algorithm.

#### Caveats

In a real life application, you would always use `Text` or `ByteString` instead of `String`, since the latter is a list of `Char` with much overhead. Since you only use a string of `'1'` and `'0'`, you can use `ByteString`:

```
import           Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import           Data.List (scanl')

slide :: Int -> ByteString -> [Int]
slide m xs = BS.zipWith f xs (BS.drop m xs)
  where
    f '1' '0' = -1
    f '0' '1' =  1
    f  _   _  =  0

slidingWindow :: Int -> ByteString -> [Int]
slidingWindow m xs = scanl' (+) start (slide m xs)
 where
   start = BS.count '1' (BS.take m xs)
```

Comment: This looks really nice. Thank you.

Comment: @dfeuer You mean instead of `ByteString` or `Text`? First of all, OP is "starting in Haskel" and I didn't want to introduce additional packages. Second, you can exchange `zipWith` and `drop` with the variants from `ByteString.(Lazy.)Char8` and you're done, so the code *almost* stays the same. Last but not least, the question is underspecified. Should the result get printed, or should it be a list? Either way, I'll add something about `String`.

Comment: @Zeta, no, I mean at all. Why not use `Bool`, or `data Bit = Zero | One` or something?

Comment: @dfeuer: *"You are given a long string of 1s and 0s of length n"*. But yeah, a `Input -> BoolString` followed by `slidingWindow :: Int -> BoolString -> …` would be better.

Comment: A "string" to a C programmer is just an array of 8-bit things. The OP appears to be an experienced C programmer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

After reading the question more carefully I noticed that the
C program reads its input from an array.

So here is an equivalent Haskell "pure" function which performs the task.

```
 import qualified Data.Vector as V
 import Data.List
 import Control.Monad

 count :: Int -> V.Vector Int -> [Int]
 count m v = 
   let c0 = V.sum (V.take m v)
       n = V.length v
       results = scanl' go c0 [0..n-m-1]
         where go r i = r - (v V.! i) + (v V.! (i+m))
   in results

 test1 = let v = V.fromList [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
         in print $ count 3 v
```

Even though `count` returns a list it will be generated lazily. Moreover, if it is consume by another list operation it could be optimized via one of the various fusion techniques.

**Original Answer**

This is a good exercise, but why does it have to be "purely functional" (and what does that mean anyway)?

You can write the C algorithm in Haskell - it's not as terse, but it will
generate essentially the same code.

```
 import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as V

 count m = do
   v <- V.replicate m '0'
   let toInt ch = if ch == '1' then 1 else 0
   let loop c i = do
         ch <- getChar
         oldch <- V.read v i
         let c' = c + toInt ch - toInt oldch
         V.write v i ch
         let i' = mod (i+1) m 
         putStrLn $ show c
         loop c' i'
   loop 0 0

 main = count 3
```

(For simplicity this generates *n* results.)

If you were benchmark this note that you are also including the performance of
`getChar` and `putStrLn` and `show`, so it might be difficult to make a fair
comparison with a C program. However, it has O(n) complexity and constant
memory usage which is what I think you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional has a definition that might be helpful but I really meant using only pure functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function .

Comment: Well - that article says that Haskell is a purely functional language. So does that mean any Haskell function is purely functional?

Comment: I don't feel I am the right expert to give a great answer to that question. However, I can say that I had immutability in mind when I asked the question.

Comment: Questions about the problem: it appears the C program reads the input from an array - is that correct? And what does it mean to "output"? Are the results placed in another array or sent to `stdout` or ...?

Comment: I am happy for the input to come in any form that is convenient and for the output to be sent directly to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic level is re-implementing the cool HOF-based algorithms with hand-written recursive functions to express the loops.

Banged patterns mark arguments as strict, so simple values can be calculated without unnecessary delay (this is implicitly taken care of when using `scanl'`, for example). This also shows that "pointers" are just names:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

-- assumes xs has only 0s and 1s
counts :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
counts m xs = g 0 m xs
  where
    g !c    0      ys  = h c ys xs
    g !c    _      []  = []                  -- m > |xs|
    g !c    m   (y:ys) = g (c+y) (m-1) ys
    h !c    []     _   = [c]
    h !c (y:ys) (x:xs) = c : h (c+y-x) ys xs
```

Testing,

```
 > counts [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1] 2
[2,1,0,1,2,1,1]
 > counts [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1] 3
[2,1,1,2,3,3]
```